# what is the difference between touch and tap in iOS

Tags: ios, uitouch

I am confused by the difference between touches and taps like `touchUpInside` event and `one tap`. Are they the same thing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html

A tap is the equivalent of a click, a rapid touch start and touch end (which counts as ONE event)

a touch can be lingering...you may touchdown, then move your finger to the button, then lifting your finger fires the touch up (inside the button)

Answer (score 7):

I have found that taps are the number of taps for the gesture to be recognized.

Touches are the number of fingers required to tap for the gesture to be recognized.

Comment: well said. Thank you